# Publish Angular 6 library to npmjs with README.md

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular6, npmjs

I'm developing a Angular 6 library which I want to publish to npmjs. The workspace (sample) and the library is versioned on [GitHub](https://github.com/AustrianStandards/ng-as-multiselect-dropdown). I've created the library by using the Angluar-CLI's command `npm library lib-name`.

The projects `README.md` is located in the root folder of the workspace project. As indicated in a [guide on Medium](https://medium.com/@tomsu/how-to-build-a-library-for-angular-apps-4f9b38b0ed11), I've built the library and used the following commands to publish to npm:

```
ng build ng-as-multiselect-dropdown --prod
cd dist/ng-as-multiselect-dropdown
npm publish
```

The library is now published at [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@austrianstandards/ng-as-multiselect-dropdown), but npmjs can't pick up the `README.md` as the readme is not located in the libraries code, but in the workspace project:

```
"Unable to find a readme for @austrianstandards/ng-as-multiselect-dropdown@1.0.0"
```

How to publish the library and include the `README.md` in the build, so both the readme gets displayed on both GitHub and npmjs?

Comment: I think you should not cd to the dist folder, but instead run: `npm publish dist`

Comment: Running `npm publish dist` from the project root folder gives me `no such file or directory, open 'dist/package.json'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a readme under projects folder and then build it and then cd to dist directory of the lib and npm publish it

This will solve your problem

Comment: I added a README.md inside in the project folder and even inside the project/my-lib folder, but it won't be exported to the dist folder... any ideas?

Comment: It should be under projects/ your module name folder @user2010955